# How do I play sounds to create a strumming effect?

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, mp3, avaudioplayer

I want to implement a simple guitar. As you know, a guitar has six strings and when you pluck one of them, the corresponding sound will play. To address the problem, I initialized six `avaudioplayers` in `viewDidLoad` and used an mp3 file. In `touchesMoved`, I check which string is touched and then play the corresponding sound. But the result is not so good when I move my finger from the second string to the sixth string quickly. Only the first 1st sound plays (i.e. the second string). Can anyone share any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

- 1 - Do not use MP3 compressed sounds but plain PCM.

iOS handles only one MP4/MP3 sound concurrently in hardware accelerated playback - additional one would be played using a software decoder.

- 2 - Use OpenAL for playing the sounds.

OpenAL is easy to use, well documented and on iOS handles (AFAIK) 32 voices concurrently without bigger drawbacks.

Comment: glad I could help. In case this answer solved your issue, please select the gray checkmark to the left of it and tap in the up-arrow. Thanks and happy coding!